# Hide all images except 1st image without CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm working on [this site](http://roldskov.sp34k.dk/produkter/cykler/mountain-bikes/specialized/enduro/) where the product images are being shown with a little "color filtering" feature.

**The problem** is that both images are visible untill you hover over a color-box, because at that time my Javascript takes over and shows/hides the current image/color (see code in the bottom).

I'm using a plugin called Slimsy to Umbraco 7 which makes the cropUrl's responsive but it doesn't work if I put a `display: none` on the `.categoryImage` containers, it must be something within the plugins.

**What I need** is to **NOT** use `display: none` on each `.categoryImage` container, but somehow hide all the images except the first one so the plugin can determine the width/height/whatever it is it needs.

**My javascript:**

```
$(".frameColor").each(function () {
    var categoryImage = $(this).parent("div").next("a").find(".categoryImage");
    categoryImage.first().show();

    if ($(categoryImage).length > 1) {
    $(this).on('mouseover', function () {
        var color = $(this).data('color').replace('#', '');

 $(".frameColor").removeClass("active");
        $(this).addClass("active");

        $(categoryImage).hide().filter(function () {
            return $(this).data('frame-color') === color;
        }).show();
    });
}
else {
    $(this).hide();
}
```

});

**My frame color:**

```
@foreach (var bikeColor in images)
                {
                    string color = bikeColor.GetPropertyValue("frameColor");
                    string[] colorSplit = color.Split(',');

                    if (colorSplit.Length == 1)
                {
                    <div class="frameColor" data-color="#@color" style="background-color:#@colorSplit[0]"></div>
                }
                else
                {
                    <div class="frameColor" data-color="#@color" style="background-image:linear-gradient(-30deg, #@colorSplit[0] 0%, #@colorSplit[0] 50%, #@colorSplit[1] 50%, #@colorSplit[1] 60%);"></div>
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

To target all of `.frameColor` except for the first one, in your `$.each()` loop, you can do

```
$(".frameColor:not(:first)").each(function () {});
```

And to hide them without using `display: none;` you can use `opacity: 0;` or `visibility: hidden;`

Comment: Hello Michael, using opacity or visibility will result in an empty container with nothing inside, it's here a display: none would be great not useful.

Comment: @S-works How would setting `opacity` to `0` "result in an empty container with nothing inside"?

Comment: Because inside the `.categoryImage` container there's an image. That image gives the container a width & height.

Comment: @S-works `css` `opacity` property value does not affect `css` `width` or `height` property values of an element. Note also, `<img>` elements at linked page do not have `width` or `height` attributes set at element. Can you include a snippet of rendered `html` at Question?

Comment: @guest271314 try and go to the link provided and inspect one of the products with two images. If you add a `opacity: 0` on that element, it won't disappear.

Comment: @S-works The _"If you add a `opacity: 0` on that element, it won't disappear."_ Cannot reproduce. When set `opacity:0` at `<img>` the image is not visible, though the box of the element is still rendered in `document`.

Comment: @guest271314 Oh yeah the image is gone but I wan't the entire element `.categoryImage` to disappear

Comment: @S-works _"Oh yeah the image is gone but I wan't the entire element `.categoryImage` to disappear"_ Use same process. Set `opacity:0` at the specific `.categoryImage` elements.